# Python: Prevent python from indexing array. list indices must be integers

Tags: python

I've tried researching this with no luck so far. I'm new to python so my apologies I'm sure there's an easy solution to this.

```
local obj = {
    'button1': [100, 750],
    'button2': {
        'loc': [100, 1750],
        'returns': 2
     }
}
```

I want some objects to have an extra property of 'returns'. If I'm looping through the object programmatically I have to check that the 'loc' array exists if I want to access it.

```
if obj[element]['loc'] is not None:
   # get array w obj[element]['loc']
else:
   # get array w obj[element]
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
# list indices must be integers
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I understand why, it's because 'button1' is an array so python starts the lookup index operation, but finds a string instead of an int. However, I need that bracket to search for my ['loc'] property on my next object. I also know that you can't use the '.' operator to index properties in python so I can't do that either...

**How could I check if a property exists without it trying to index the previous object's array.**

Comment: why not have button1 be `{ 'loc': [100, 750], 'returns': None }`? consistency ftw.

Comment: You could probably make the check with a ```try ... catch```, by trying to get the property by index and if it breaks, then you know it must be the other kind

Comment: Agreed, excellent suggestion! I'll definitely go that route. Still is there no way to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if isinstance(obj[element], dict) and 'loc' in obj[element]:
```

Alternatively, you can use `try` ... `except` to catch the exception:

```
try:
    # do something with obj[element]['loc']
except TypeError:
    pass
```

Comment: awesome thanks! will accept the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below:

```
if type(obj[element]) is dict and obj[element]['loc'] is not None:
```